# Upgrade Materialize 1.0.0 -> 1.1.0

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I'm working on a `React` tutorial [project](https://github.com/bradtraversy/it-logger), that was using `Materialize 1.0.0`

The old code imported the css and js files straight from the materialize-css package like this:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';
```

I uninstalled the `materialize-css` package, and installed `@materializecss/materialize` which is the next version of `Materialize`. Following the old logic, I'm trying to import the scc and js files like this:

```
import '@materializecss/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import M from '@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js'; // <-- Error here
```

I keep getting a warning message from VS Code that says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js'. 'e:/.../node_modules/@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/materializecss__materialize` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js';`ts(7016)
module "e:/Web Dev/Brad Traversy - React Front To Back/03-it-logger/node_modules/@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize"
```

Comment: There is no materialize 1.1.0 - 1.0.0 is the current and latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using M variable anymore.

```
import '@materializecss/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import '@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js';
```

I only import both files once in my App.js, and I access `M` through `window.M`, e.g.:

```
        // Init Materialize JS
        window.M.AutoInit();
```